# Repeating single DataFrame with changing DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have very simple DataFrame like this:
`df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 12, size=(12, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'), index=pd.date_range("2000-01-01", freq="M", periods=12))`

Output:

```sh
             A  B   C   D
2010-01-31   6  0   8  10
2010-02-28   7  8  10   3
2010-03-31  10  5   8  10
2010-04-30   4  4   9   7
2010-05-31   2  3   0  11
2010-06-30   8  7  10   8
2010-07-31  11  9   0   4
2010-08-31   0  3   8   6
2010-09-30   4  6   7   9
2010-10-31   1  0  11   9
2010-11-30   5  4   8   4
2010-12-31   1  4   5   1
```

I would like to take this DataFrame and create longer that would append DataFrame itself with changing year of index. Something like this:

```sh
             A  B   C   D
2010-01-31   6  0   8  10
2010-02-28   7  8  10   3
2010-03-31  10  5   8  10
2010-04-30   4  4   9   7
2010-05-31   2  3   0  11
2010-06-30   8  7  10   8
2010-07-31  11  9   0   4
2010-08-31   0  3   8   6
2010-09-30   4  6   7   9
2010-10-31   1  0  11   9
2010-11-30   5  4   8   4
2010-12-31   1  4   5   1
2011-01-31   6  0   8  10
2011-02-28   7  8  10   3
2011-03-31  10  5   8  10
2011-04-30   4  4   9   7
2011-05-31   2  3   0  11
2011-06-30   8  7  10   8
2011-07-31  11  9   0   4
2011-08-31   0  3   8   6
2011-09-30   4  6   7   9
2011-10-31   1  0  11   9
2011-11-30   5  4   8   4
2011-12-31   1  4   5   1
2012-01-31   6  0   8  10
2012-02-28   7  8  10   3
2012-03-31  10  5   8  10
2012-04-30   4  4   9   7
2012-05-31   2  3   0  11
2012-06-30   8  7  10   8
2012-07-31  11  9   0   4
2012-08-31   0  3   8   6
2012-09-30   4  6   7   9
2012-10-31   1  0  11   9
2012-11-30   5  4   8   4
2012-12-31   1  4   5   1
```

It's still the same DataFrame, repeating again and again, and year is incrementally changed.

I could do something like this (example for 3 years):

```py
data_new = pd.concat([df] * 3)
data_new.index = np.ravel([df.index.map(lambda t: t.replace(year=year)) for year in [2010, 2011, 2012]])
```

I have mainly two questions:

- Is there a way how to do this in a single command?
- What is the best way how to deal with leap-year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option with applying `DateOffset` to the original index in list comprehension:

```
data_new = pd.concat([
    df.set_index(df.index + pd.DateOffset(year=x)) for x in [2010, 2011, 2012]])
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for, I even forgot that `DateOffset` works correctly with respect to specific calendar events like leap-year. The only last question - do you know why your proposed solution raises `PerformanceWarning`? Specifically `Non-vectorized DateOffset being applied to Series or DatetimeIndex`?

Comment: There's a note in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html) that *some offsets (such as BQuarterEnd) do not have a vectorized implementation. They can still be used but may calculate significantly slower and will show a PerformanceWarning*. It's not an error, just a warning, so if it performs reasonably well for your application, it should be safe to ignore

Comment: Actually, it looks like if you're OK with using relative year shift (as opposed to absolute), that option has a vectorized version: `df.index + pd.DateOffset(years=x)) for x in [10, 11, 12]]` (note using `years` instead of `year`) should not raise that warning, and I'm getting a ~40% speedup with this (although with dataset this small it's 3ms vs 5ms, so not really significant)

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I'm interested in replace, so your solution works perfectly and if I understand this correctly, there might be no vectorized version for replace, but only for add operation (relative year shift).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply change 12 to 36 (or whatever) in size and periods?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 12, size=(36, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'), index=pd.date_range("2000-01-01", freq="M", periods=36))
```

Comment: Sure, I could do this, but this was only for demonstration. In fact I get single year data in DataFrame by reading CSV and then I want to do this duplication with changing index.